# AWS RDS IAM Role credential rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, credentials

AWS documentation says that the IAM credentials are rotated every 15 mins.

Suppose at time `T = 0 mins` I create an authentication token `t1`, and at `T = 14 mins`, I create another token `t2`.

When time `T = 16 mins`, token t1 will obviously be invalid, will token `t2` also be invalid? Or will token `t2` be valid till the 29th minute?

Because in case of the latter I will be able to set `MaxConnLifetime` at say 14 mins without having to worry about closing the connection.

From the `boto` source code it looks like the token is a presigned HTTP request. Any clarity on this would be great. Also if this is mentioned in the AWS docs, please link me to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an authentication token"? Are you calling `AssumeRole`? Can you point us to the particular documentation you mentioned?

Comment: `An authentication token is a unique string of characters that Amazon RDS generates on request. Authentication tokens are generated using AWS Signature Version 4. Each token has a lifetime of 15 minutes. You don't need to store user credentials in the database, because authentication is managed externally using IAM. You can also still use standard database authentication.`

@JohnRotenstein the authentication token mentioned here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html

Answer (score 0):

The URL will look something like this:

> rdspostgres.123456789012.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/?Action=connect&DBUser=jane_doe&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA22BX4KO8BHD63AUG%2F20210619%2Fus-west-2%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210619T081640Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=93281b4fe39f7ea85c41e56464a0c1e26ad59fe5edbafb41a2e7f5fc18f0078f

It includes a timestamp and an expiry period (900 seconds). Every time that command is called, it will generate a different token with the current timestamp. Multiple tokens can be valid at the same time, as long as they are within 15 minutes (900 seconds) of being generated.

I suspect that these tokens simply allow the user to **login**. I doubt they would have an impact on session duration of the database connection (but feel free to correct me if you know better).